# Do anyone have any idea on how to compare the dates within the daterangepicker?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

This's slightly different with the normal one.

Normally, we will use two input controls to store two dates which are "start date" and "End Date".

In this case, there's only one input control which utilizes the daterangepicker. By having one id only, how am I going to make comparison with two dates generated from the daterangepicker?

```
$('input[name="dates"]').daterangepicker();
```

The image below reveals two dates. How am I going to store these two dates by having only one id which come from the input control.

[Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JM0JE.png)

Comment: Can you please confirm which date range picker control are you using.Also provide some sample code of the implementation

Comment: Please provide also when the event is going to be raised. Another button? On blur of the textbox? On blur of daterangepicker? MAybe on the daterangepicker can you disable any date?

Comment: @Emanuele Event will be raised by clicking the textbox

Comment: At this moment, I have no any code behind for it. I have only the design of it. That's why I'm here to seek for guidance from you guys. Haha @SreenathGanga

Comment: @JackieYong There is more than one daterangepicker available. Which one did you use? Can you give us a link to its documentation?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [daterangepicker.com](http://www.daterangepicker.com/), your dates will be [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) objects accessible in daterangepicker events such as apply.daterangepicker.

You can use moment's .diff() method on the first date,supply the second date as param one and the time increment as param two (in this case 'days').

I used Math.abs() to ensure I get a positive return.

```html
    $('#date_input').daterangepicker({    
        // ...
    }).on('apply.daterangepicker', function (ev, picker) {
        var start = picker.startDate;
        var end = picker.endDate;
        console.log(Math.abs(start.diff(end, 'days')));
    })
```

I hope this is the daterangepicker you're looking for.